# How to fix addEventListener that does not work?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

my code have two addEventListener() the first one is fine but the second one have a problem

```js
let catNames = ['pew', 'haha', 'Tsh', 'bom', 'tok'];
let catPhotos = document.querySelectorAll('li img');
let catNamePlaces = document.querySelectorAll('li p');
let area = document.getElementById('area');
let targetName = document.querySelector('#area p');
let targetImg = document.querySelector('#area img');
let counterArea = document.querySelector('#area div');

for (let i = 0; i < catNames.length; i++) {
  catNamePlaces[i].textContent = catNames[i];
}
for (let catPhoto of catPhotos) {
  catPhoto.addEventListener('click', function() {
    targetImg.src = catPhoto.src;
  }, false);
}
let counter = 0;

targetImg.addEventListener('click', (function(num) {
  num++;
  counterArea.innerHTML = num;
})(counter));
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat1.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat2.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat3.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat4.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat5.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
</ul>
<div id="area">
  <p></p>
  <img src="" alt="selectedCat">
  <div id="counter"></div>
</div>
```

I expect from the second addEventListener that it will start from 0 then add one every time will be clicked on the targetImg but what is every time start from 1 and do nothing when I chick on it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let catNames = ['pew', 'haha', 'Tsh', 'bom', 'tok'];
let catPhotos = document.querySelectorAll('li img');
let catNamePlaces = document.querySelectorAll('li p');
let area = document.getElementById('area');
let targetName = document.querySelector('#area p');
let targetImg = document.querySelector('#area img');
let counterArea = document.querySelector('#area div');

for (let i = 0; i < catNames.length; i++) {
  catNamePlaces[i].textContent = catNames[i];
}
for (let catPhoto of catPhotos) {
  catPhoto.addEventListener('click', function() {
    targetImg.src = catPhoto.src;
  }, false);
}
let counter = 0;
counterArea.innerHTML = counter;

targetImg.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  counter++;
  counterArea.innerHTML = counter;
});
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat1.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat2.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat3.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat4.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
  <li>
    <p></p><img src="cat5.jpg" alt="cat"></li>
</ul>
<div id="area">
  <p></p>
  <img src="" alt="selectedCat">
  <div id="counter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is not useful. What did you change and why?

Answer (score 0):

```
// this part does not change
let catNames = ['pew', 'haha', 'Tsh', 'bom', 'tok'];
let catPhotos = document.querySelectorAll('li img');
let catNamePlaces = document.querySelectorAll('li p');
let area = document.getElementById('area');
let targetName = document.querySelector('#area p');
let targetImg = document.querySelector('#area img');
let counterArea = document.querySelector('#counter');

for (let i = 0; i < catNames.length; i++) {
  catNamePlaces[i].textContent = catNames[i];
}

// since here there is some changes
var counter = 0;

for (let catPhoto of catPhotos) {
    console.log(catPhoto)
    catPhoto.addEventListener('click', function() {
    targetImgFun(catPhoto.src); // call new function with cat src
  }, false);
}

function targetImgFun(src) {
  targetImg.src = src; // update src
  counter++; // counter +1
  counterArea.innerHTML = counter; // update counter output
}
```

Add a function to get specific target, then add +1 to counter and display it

Comment: Okay Now it is increment +1 but when I click on catPhotos  not on the targetImg

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `num` variable to be incremented everytime you click on the image you need to define it in the outer scope of the function so that it retains the value between the function calls.

Add the declaration just under your already define variables:

`var num = 0;`

and remove the parameter from the function

```
targetImg.addEventListener('click', (function() {
  num++;
  counterArea.innerHTML = num;
}));
```